# How access to value of a variable in flutter package from other widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I wrote a `package` for `Flutter` and added it to the main.dart and it works well but How can I access the value of one of the variables in the package? or how return a variables from it ? For example, in the `slider` widget, we have access to the value of the slider with on change .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to learn how to manage state in flutter.

There are couple of good state management tools:

[provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) seems to be the easiest one.

Here is a nice tutorial on provider:

https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-tutorial-app-arhitecture-beginners/